# Slow paging speed on 500,000 records in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, pagination

I use this stored procedure for pagination in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [SelectPaging]
@SelectedColumn nvarchar(max),
@ViewName nvarchar(200),
@PrimaryKeyName nvarchar(100),
@RowCountOnPage int,
@PageNumberDesired int,
@Condition nvarchar(max),
@OrderBy nvarchar(200),
@OrderByAsc bit,
@UserID int,
@ErrorNumber int out,
@TotalRowsCount int out
as
begin
SET NOCOUNT ON;

Begin Try



    exec [general].TotalRowsWithFiltering @PrimaryKeyName,@viewName ,@Condition ,@UserID,@TotalRowsCount out,@ErrorNumber out


    declare @RowNumberFrom int,@RowNumberTo int
    set @RowNumberFrom=((@PageNumberDesired-1)*@RowCountOnPage)
    set @RowNumberTo=(@PageNumberDesired*@RowCountOnPage)+1

    if @Condition='' or @Condition is null
    set @Condition=' 1=1 '
    else set @Condition=@Condition

    if @OrderBy='' or @OrderBy is null
    set @OrderBy=@PrimaryKeyName
    declare @OrderByAsc_Desc nvarchar(6)
    if (@OrderByAsc='false' or @OrderByAsc is null)
        set @OrderByAsc_Desc=' Desc'
    else if @OrderByAsc='true'
        set @OrderByAsc_Desc=' Asc'


    declare @SQLQuery nvarchar(max)


set @SQLQuery='SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by '+@OrderBy+' '+@OrderByAsc_Desc+') AS RowNumber
  FROM (
    SELECT '+@SelectedColumn+'
    FROM '+@viewName+' where  ' + @Condition +'
  ) AS d
) AS c
where RowNumber >'+cast(@RowNumberFrom as nvarchar(10))+' and RowNumber <  '+cast(@RowNumberTo as nvarchar(10))


    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLQuery

    set @ErrorNumber=@@ERROR

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

END CATCH


end
```

I run the query on the view with 700.000 record.
When I select query on the view, the runtime is zero.
But when I run this sp for pagination, it takes 50-60 seconds for fetching 10 record for each page

How can it be optimized?

Comment: You really should consider upgrading your SQL Server version. Extended support for 2008 is ending next month. That being said, there's no reason to think [what worked on 2000](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/042606-1.shtml) souldn't work on 2008.

Comment: @Zohar Peled: What SQL Server Version do you recommend to solve this problem?

Comment: Not to solve this particular problem, but in general, it's always better to work with supported versions. AFAIK Last stable version is 2017 (2019 is still preview) and 2012 is soon going to be the oldest supported version. You should upgrade to at least 2-3 versions above so you wouldn't have to upgrade again too soon - so 2016-2017 should be a good choice.

Comment: That looks like a huge injection nightmare. You need to be quoting your objects. You're giving someone to chance to use an `nvarchar(MAX)` when a column's max length is 128 characters as well. In truth, that entire SO needs to go; it's a huge security risk.

Comment: A explain plan and table structures would be nice..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for pagination....OFFSET is supported sql server 2012+ version. So first upgrade your server version.. Then create an index in your table for fast searching

```
   declare @Page bigint=1,@pageSize bigint = 20

    SELECT * FROM AC_TRN_STOCKHEADER 
    Order by HEADER_ID desc 
    OFFSET  (@Page-1) ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY

-----==================================
-----Code to Create an index
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_HEADER_ID ON YOUR_TABLE_NAME (KEY_FIELD_OF_TABLE)

ON THE ABOVE CODE "AC_TRN_STOCKHEADER" is my Table Name and "Header_ID" is my Key_FIELD
Hence,
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_HEADER_ID ON AC_TRN_STOCKHEADER (Header_ID)
```

Hope it will resolve your problem..

Comment: having to need to use a large `OFFSET` number is a simply a huge no go for performance, i advice you to read [this](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset)